# convert loc expression from pandas to Pyspark?

Tags: python, pandas, apache-spark, pyspark

How can I convert this expression from pandas to Pyspark Dataframe?

The target is to assign the column date_stamp the value cur

```py
#the data frame is:
tag,     2020-06-25
-------------------
3FMTK1RM    0
678jhgt     18

#######################
vin='3FMTK1RM'# is the first element of tag
cur= 5
date_stamp='2020-06-25'
df.loc[str(date_stamp),vin] = cur
```

Comment: Spark dataframe is an unordered collection of rows. You cannot access/modify elements by index.

Comment: Is there a way of creating a new Dataframe then do the union ?

Comment: union of what..?

Comment: Is there a way that I can share the code with you ?

Comment: You can post it in your question using the edit function

Comment: The code is long a little complex , I tried to simplify it as possible

Comment: Hello @insses0606. Your question is not clear and not all spark users know how to use pandas. Please make it more understandable by adding a reproducible example, your input spark data frame and the desired output. You see this post on how make good pyspark examples: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48427185/how-to-make-good-reproducible-apache-spark-examples

Comment: you can use Koalas: https://koalas.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `when`:

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as F

df2 = df.withColumn(
    '2020-06-25', 
    F.when(F.col('tag') == 'vin', cur).otherwise(F.col('2020-06-25'))
)
```